# registerDeviceToken is deprecated

Tags: ios6, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am having an app in which I am using Urban Airship for Push Notifications.

I am having a code below.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    UALOG(@"APN device token: %@", deviceToken);
    // Updates the device token and registers the token with UA
    [[UAirship shared] registerDeviceToken:deviceToken];

}
```

I am getting a warning of register devicetoken is deprecated:deprecated as in libUAirship1.3.0.

What is an alternative for this in ios6?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with [UrbanAirship documentation](http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/ios.html?highlight=registerdevicetoken) you must use : `[[UAPush shared] registerDeviceToken:deviceToken];`

Comment: Nope, it's from their documentation so it's recommended like that, you can read to see how is used in there.

Comment: No problem , glad that i could help.